# How can the word "benchmark" be a noun?

Tags: grammar

I was taught in my high school that a noun can be a person, place, animal or a thing? The word "benchmark" does not qualify to be any one of them yet it is considered as a noun

Can someone please explain me how?

Comment: As Araucaria's answer to the linked question says, a noun doesn't have to fall into any of these three categories. However, if you want to, you could consider a benchmark a "thing".

Comment: It *is* a "thing." Look up *thing*: "an action, event, thought, or utterance" and more. Also @sumelic

Answer (score 1):

A noun can also be an abstract thought, idea, or concept. It doesn't have to be a physical object to be considered a noun.

A good example is that numbers (1, 2, 3...) are also considered nouns.

Answer (score 1):

I used to visit benchmarks (or "bench marks" as we called them) when I worked for the UK Ordnance Survey, the government's mapping agency. They are measuring points, placed on fixed landscape features or buildings, used by surveyors.  The noun later came to have a figurative use, and finally to also be a verb.

Here is a picture of an OS bench mark:

[image]

Comment: It was first a noun before it was a verb, then?

Comment: @Kris Yes. My question might have been .. 'How can benchmark be a verb?' It's one of many examples of nouns 'being transitioned' (yuk) to verbs by Business-English users.

Comment: @RobinBetts Yuk or not, "verbing" is real and, lately, with no rules.